# remove option from second select if already selected first

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a sports betting page. The User needs to select which 2 teams are playing each other.
So, I have two `select`s, and I need to remove an `option` from the second `select`, because a team can't play itself.
Here are the selects:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="team1">
        <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
        <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
        <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="team2">
        <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
        <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
        <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tried anything...I don't even have a clue :(

Comment: Then you have to do some research or hire a developer.

Comment: you have to move `filter` concepts. based on 1st selection , then 2nd selection is filtered.

Comment: javascript's Select Remove Method() will help you in this..  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp) has a nice tutorial

Comment: @Anish—please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of errors. [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) is a much better resource.

Comment: @RobG ... okay, I will keep this in mind.. thanks.. :)

Comment: Well I am currently learning development. I have just learned some PHP and Javascript (basics). I will learn jquery as well. Thank you all guys for helping me.

Comment: @cata—there is no need to learn jQuery for this, you can achieve the result you want in POJS without a library or additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Jquery solution for you:

```js
$('select[name=team2]').on('change', function() {
   var self = this;
   $('select[name=team1]').find('option').prop('disabled', function() {
       return this.value == self.value
   });
});

$('select[name=team1]').on('change', function() {
  var self = this;
  $('select[name=team2]').find('option').prop('disabled', function() {
      return this.value == self.value
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="team1">
  <option value="">Please select a team...</option>
  <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
  <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
  <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="team2">
  <option value="">Please select a team...</option>
  <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
  <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
  <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, you can do this without a library, and without additional code. This solution also uses fewer function calls, and direct property access rather than selectors, so it should be more efficient.

The strategy is to disable whichever option that is chosen in the other select. Meanwhile, it enables all the other options.
Disabling options may not work in older browsers - you may have to remove and replace them instead.

```js
window.onload = function(){

  document.forms[0].team1.addEventListener('change', function(){
    [].forEach.call(this.form.team2.options, function(opt) {
      opt.disabled = opt.index == this.selectedIndex && opt.index != 0;
    }, this);
  }, false);
  
  document.forms[0].team2.addEventListener('change', function(){
    [].forEach.call(this.form.team1.options, function(opt) {
      opt.disabled = opt.index == this.selectedIndex && opt.index != 0;
    }, this);
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="form-control" name="team1">
    <option>Select one&hellip;
    <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
    <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
    <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
    <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
    <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" name="team2">
    <option>Select one&hellip;
    <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
    <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
    <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
    <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
    <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The above solution also allows the user to select the first option ('Select one…') in both selects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in `jQuery`

```
$('.form-control[name=team1]').on('change', function(e){
   var thisVal = $(this).val();
   $('.form-control[name=team2] option').each(function(){
      if(thisVal == $(this).attr('value')){
         $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       }else{
         $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
       }
   })
})
```

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/uLqpfqr7/

Comment: Code only answers aren't that helpful, and should not rely on a library that is not tagged or noted in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this example:** you can handle both select box

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#team1").change(function(){
   var anotherTeam = $("#team2").val();
   var team = $(this).val();
   if(team !='' && team==anotherTeam){
     alert("This team already selected.");
     $('option:selected',this).removeAttr('selected');
     $("option:first",this).attr('selected','selected');
   }
 });
     
 $("#team2").change(function(){
   var anotherTeam = $("#team1").val();
   var team = $(this).val();
   if(team !='' && team==anotherTeam){
     alert("This team already selected.");
     $('option:selected',this).removeAttr('selected');
     $("option:first",this).attr('selected','selected');
     
   }
 });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="team1" id="team1">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
  <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
  <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="team2" id="team2">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="Steaua Bucuresti">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="CSU Craiova">CSU Craiova</option>
  <option value="FC Viitorul">FC Viitorul</option>
  <option value="Dinamo Bucuresti">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
  <option value="Pandurii Tg Jiu">Pandurii Tg Jiu</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for long term value, and quality. Highlight the important or unique parts of your routine, so future visitors can quickly learn from your solution, and apply it to their own issues. Code only answers are frowned upon on SO. Accordingly, quality answers are more likely to be upvoted. Please consider editing to improve your post. Thanks for your contributions.