# By selecting element in one selection Box another selection box can't be selected i.e. another selection box will be in hidden format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select Language:</option>
    <option value="1">HTML</option>
    <option value="2">RUBY</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

After selecting one select box another can't be edited

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
      <select>
        <option value="0">Select Language:</option>
       <option value="1">HTML</option>
       <option value="2">RUBY</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

The above selection menu can't be selected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove option from second select if already selected first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931449/remove-option-from-second-select-if-already-selected-first)

Comment: insert html and css

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. It is not clear what you mean unless you post CSS and relevant script and possibly frameworks like bootstrap or similar

Answer (score 0):

This should help. You will however need JQuery to make this work.

```js
$('select[name=select1]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name=select2]').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select name="select1">
    <option selected disabled value="0">Select Language:</option>
    <option value="1">HTML</option>
    <option value="2">RUBY</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select name="select2">
    <option value="0">Select Language:</option>
    <option value="1">HTML</option>
    <option value="2">RUBY</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```